# Eclipse Text/Code Overly Spaced Out, Can't Fix

Tags: java, eclipse

So today when I opened up my Eclipse, I discovered that the code/text in the window was overly spaced out. This has happened to me once before and I was able to fix it, but I forgot how I did so. I have tried Window-> Perspective->Reset Perspective and it does not fix it. I also feel the font is different then it should be.
Here is an image of my eclipse.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tnbox.png

How do I fix this? Thanks :).

Comment: What is wrong in it ?

Comment: The last time I opened Eclipse (along with all of the previous times..) the text was a LOT less spaced out, and I believe the font was different. I can tell this has changed because it just seems different to me, and the documentation extends out of view now, when it used to all be in view without having to scroll.

Comment: Some Unicode (Chinese for example) characters force the extra spacing.

Comment: I did have a java update prior to opening eclipse, so is it possible that has had an effect?

Comment: There isn't any unicode in my project. The last time I closed eclipse everything was fine. When I went to open it today I had not touched a single thing in the code and it is now appearing differently.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/9ti8c0 here is a random image I found to show how it used to look.

http://prntscr.com/9ti8yq here is how mine now looks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fix: I was doing some more digging around and apparently the font I was completely used to was "Consolas". I have no idea how it was changed, but I assume the Java 8 update affected it.